# symfony program hangs up when calling database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

Hi I am using the Doctrine ORM with symphony, was able to build the tables with the database generator but when I try to run the http://localhost:8080//frontend_dev.php/cines  it hangs up on the line with the query as I can see in the log symfony [info] {Doctrine_Connection_Mysql} query :  etc.

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: will you check apache & mysql error logs

Answer (score 0):

From what you've mentioned it sounds like you haven't set up your models. You can do so by typing:

```
$php symfony doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation
```

at the command line. Hope this helps.